# Convert .mbox files to .sql

Tags: email, database, file-converter

I am looking for a program that can convert .mbox files to .sql (or directly insert .mbox data into some database). It should run on Windows or Linux.

If possible:

- Gratis
- Open source
- can handle large .mbox files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Free and open source" - given that requirements, I guess your best shot is to create a small Perl script, utilizing the modules [Mail::Mbox::MessageParser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Mbox-MessageParser/lib/Mail/Mbox/MessageParser/Perl.pm) and [SQL::Generator](http://search.cpan.org/~muenalan/SQL-Generator-0.02/Generator.pm). For Python, the module "[mailbox](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html)" might be of use, as well as the [mogrify function from Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify). Should not be too hard for someone with >5K points at Stackoverflow.

If you are looking for a solution where you don't have to program anything, forget "free and open source". Google for "read mbox excel", that will bring you to some commercial solutions to import mbox into an Excel sheet. You will surely find canned solutions to insert Excel sheets into the database of your choice.